# How to get a thread submitted to executer service and interrupt it in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have an executor service, and I want to cancel/interrupt the execution of some of the threads.

For example: Below is my Thread class which prints the thread name after some interval infinitely.

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
String name;

public MyThread(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Thread "+ name + " is running");
        sleep(500);
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("got the interrupted signal");
    }
}
}
```

Now I'll create multiple threads by giving them name, so that later on I can stop a particular thread with it's name.

As shown below, I am creating 4 threads and want to stop the execution of 2 threads named **foo** and **bar**.

```
public class ThreadTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    MyThread amit = new MyThread("foo");
    MyThread k = new MyThread("bar");
    MyThread blr = new MyThread("tel-aviv");
    MyThread india = new MyThread("israel");
    executorService.submit(foo);
    executorService.submit(bar);
    executorService.submit(tel-aviv);
    executorService.submit(israel);
}
}
```

Comment: Hint: `executorService.submit` gives you back a `Future<?>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner , i know it gives a `Future` but can you let me know how can i use it in my case to retrive the threads with name `amit` and interrupt its execution ?

Comment: Your `MyThread` doesn't need to extend `Thread`. Just implement `Runnable`.

Comment: Just keep the futures in a Map<String,Future<?>> by name so you can look them up by whatever name you like.

Comment: @AmitK your `MyThread`s are not actually being run on threads with those names. They're not being run directly as threads, they are run on the `ExecutorService`'s threads. So, you need to keep a mapping of name to `Future`, and then cancel the future when you want to.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for the hint, i'll try this and update.

Comment: @AndyTurner is it possible to give my own name to the thread to make the logging and debugging easy ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `MyThread`s are not actually being run on threads with those names. They're not being run directly as threads, they are run on the `ExecutorService`'s threads.

So, you need to keep a mapping of name to `Future`, and then cancel the future when you want to.

```
Map<String, Future<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("amit", executorService.submit(amit));
map.put("k", executorService.submit(k));
// ... etc
```

Then, to cancel `amit`:

```
map.get("amit").cancel(true);
```

Of course, you could simply have kept explicit variables:

```
Future<?> amitFuture = executorService.submit(amit);
amitFuture.cancel(true);
```

but this might be unwieldy if you have a lot of variables.

Comment: Also is it possible to give me own name to the thread to make the logging and debugging easy ?